# Xamarin Deployed Faild Object Reference Not Set To An Instance

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, xamarin.android

I've been trying to setup mobile development on **VS2015** for several days. The issue is

1. I created blank app
2. Started Emulator From Xamarin Android Player
3. Started Debugging

I got my solution `built succeed` but `deploy failed`. Here is image

[image: Xamarin deploy error]

I checked the error list but as we can see it is nothing there.

Well, I searched on internet with different queries and came to know that this problem is quite common but no permanent solution is provided. Some of the solutions suggested on other sites including **Xamarin Official Forums** are as follows:

- Restart debugger.
- Install valid Java Sdk Manager.
- Restart Visual Studio.
- Install android packages for targeted platform.
- Create virtual device.
- Change settings in Hyper-V manager.
- Set your project as **Startup** Project.
- Uninstall android components and reinstall them.
- Disable Fast Deployment Option in Project Properties.

I tried everything but issue stands still. The packages I have installed for **SDK** are in image as follows

[image: SDK Installed Packages]
[image]

I don't know what part of package installation I am missing or there is some problem with **VS2015**. I have been trying to resolve this deployment issue but in vain.

**Note*: I am using HP EliteBook 8460p with Win 10 64-bit installed on it.**

Comment: The code is trying to run the program and failing inside the program.  Put a break point on 1st instruction in the program and see if you get to the break point.

Comment: Solved it. Problem was setting minimum target for application. In my case I set it to the Jellybean 4.1. It deployed successfully. Thanks For Response.